# Transpose Columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Let´s say I have the following table:
[image]
Produced by the following python Code

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["Car","Sport","Wheel", 4], 
        ["Car", "Sport","engine HP", 65], 
        ["Car", "Sport","windows", 5], 
        ["Car","Van","Wheel", 4], 
        ["Car", "Van","engine HP", 85], 
        ["Car", "Van","windows", 8],
        ["Truck","Small","Wheel", 4], 
        ["Truck", "Small","engine HP", 125], 
        ["Truck", "Small","windows", 2],
        ["Truck","Large","Wheel", 8], 
        ["Truck", "Large","engine HP", 200], 
        ["Truck", "Large","windows", 2]
        ]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#define header names
df.columns = ["Vehicle", "Type","Parameter","Value"]

df here
```

How do I manipulate by Dataframe to transpose the parameter value if **, I don't know in advance the content of the parameter columns, or how many type of parameters there might be.**

The end result would be the following table

```py
"Vehicle","Type","Wheel","Engine","Windows"

"Car","Sport",4,65,51

"Car","Van",4,85,8

"Truck","Small",4,125,2
"Truck","Large",8,200,2
```

Comment: why don't you use the built-in method of transpose provided by pandas?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you want to do.  In addition to showing your original data, can you show the result that you desire?  If you want to do a trivial transpose operation, then just call `df.transpose()`.  I'm guessing that because you talk about needing to know details of the data, you want to do something more complex.

Comment: @CryptoFool yes, the table at the end is the result I want to get

Comment: use the following code:   df.pivot(index=["Vehicle", "Type"], columns="Parameter", values="Value")

Answer (score 0):

You can try the built-in transpose method provided by pandas.

You can have a look about [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Comment: Thank you, but The Transpose method would apply to the whole table and not produce the output table at the end of the question